# Marshalling hashmap with Jackson to XML - wrong structure

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, jax-rs

I have a `Hashmap<String, List<Object>>` and I want to marshal the map with Jackson. It's working with JSON perfectly and looks like this:

```
{
    "entriesByTable": {
        "Karlsruhe": [
            {
                "counts": 126,
                "hashTag": "#Karlsruhe"
            },
            {
                "counts": 26,
                "hashTag": "#jobs"
            },
            {
                "counts": 3,
                "hashTag": "#etka16"
            }, ...
```

But when it comes to XML my structure looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Database>
  <entriesByTable>
    <Karlsruhe>
      <hashTag>#Karlsruhe</hashTag>
      <counts>127</counts>
    </Karlsruhe>
    <Karlsruhe>
      <hashTag>#jobs</hashTag>
      <counts>27</counts>
    </Karlsruhe>
    <Karlsruhe>
      <hashTag>#etka16</hashTag>
      <counts>3</counts>
    </Karlsruhe> ...
```

But I want/need the same Json-strucutre:

```
<Database>
 <entriesByTable> (mapname)
  <Karlsruhe>     (key)
   <entries>      (value (list))
    <entry>
     <counts>126</counts>
     <hashTag>#Karlsruhe</hashtag>
    </entry>
   </entries>
  </Karlsruhe>
 </entriesByTable>
</Database>
```

My class:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement
public class Database {

    private static String DATABASE_LOCATION;

    @JsonProperty
    private Map<String, List<DatabankEntry>> entriesByTable = new HashMap<>(); ...
```

Second class:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement
public class DatabankEntry implements Comparable<DatabankEntry> {

    @JsonIgnore
    private String tableName;

    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private String hashTag;
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private int counts;
```

Would be awesome if someone has an idea. Maybe I made a mistake with the annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I handled the problem by myself. I created a new class which contains a list of entries and annotated the listobject.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DatabaseEntries {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Entry")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName="Entries")
    @JsonProperty
    private List<DatabaseEntry> databaseEntries = new LinkedList<>();

    public int size(){
        return databaseEntries.size();
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public List<DatabaseEntry> getAllEntries(){
        Collections.sort(databaseEntries);
        return databaseEntries;
    }

    public void add(DatabaseEntry databaseEntry){
        databaseEntries.add(databaseEntry)  ;
        }

}
```

My Hashmap looks like this now `Hashmap<String,Object>`

```
@JsonProperty
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "EntriesByTable")
private Map<String, DatabaseEntries> entriesByTable = new HashMap<>();
```

and my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Database>
  <EntriesByTable>
    <Karlsruhe>
      <Entries>
        <Entry>
          <HashTag>#Karlsruhe</HashTag>
          <Counts>700</Counts>
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
          <HashTag>#Feuerwehr</HashTag>
          <Counts>114</Counts>
        </Entry>
....
```

JSON:

```
{
    "entriesByTable": {
        "Karlsruhe": {
            "databaseEntries": [
                {
                    "counts": 700,
                    "hashTag": "#Karlsruhe"
                },
                {
                    "counts": 114,
                    "hashTag": "#Feuerwehr"
                },
```